# Apache2 Web Server 502 Error

Tags: apache-2.2

So I went to bed last night with my Apache webserver working fine, and I wake up to a bunch of people telling me they can't reach my website, spootur.com.

The way this is networked is a bit weird. It's inside a college network, but is accessible from the outside because it uses a public IP. The strange thing is that I don't get any error when accessing the site from inside the network, but anyone outside of the college network receives the 502 error.

I didn't change anything on the server since I went to bed (it was working fine then). Any idea on what could be causing this? Also: I'm only using the default Apache mods

Comment: Are entries appearing in Apache's logs for the 502 responses?

Comment: No entries have appeared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the public IP?  A `502 Bad gateway` error usually indicates that the public IP cannot be redirected to your private, internal server.  Try doing a `traceroute` on the external IP--I bet it never makes it your internal server.  Furthermore, if you're not seeing any requests in your `access_log` from the external IP, there's your answer.

Comment: Yea, it never makes it to the internal network. Looks like it's out of my control :(

Comment: Yeah, that's what I guessed; looks like you're going to have to talk to your college network admins.  If they hadn't given you express permission, they may have revoked it (college admins are typically very strict about this).  If not, they may not have known it was supposed to be kept up.  Your best bet is to talk to them!

Comment: No problem; sorry the issue couldn't be resolved on your end!  I hope your college's admins are nice... :)